# C++, GPIO, separate data & clock lines

Tags: c++, gpio

I'm developing for the Beaglebone Black under QT Creator, C++.

I have a signal with a clock assigned to one GPIO port, and a data line assigned to another port.

How do I read this data in?

Comment: Consider supplying the code.

Comment: Have you searched the internet for "C++ BeagleBone Black read gpio"?  What were your results?

Comment: Nothing came up.

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: see the various comments in this google group discussion, [Beaglebone Black libraries for GPIO access in C/C++?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/Mef65w6PZ7s) and see also [GPIO on Beaglebone Black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34261512/gpio-on-beaglebone-black).

Comment: Hi NuPagadi: I'm trying to write the code, and don't know how to start.  Reading and setting an individual line I can do, but this is a signal with a clock and a data line.

Comment: Hi Thomas Matthews: I tried searching the Internet and after a few dozen tries I found no examples of people trying to read a signal on GPIO lines with a data and a clock line.

Comment: Hi doron.  Debian Linux 7.3  I know we should upgrade, but we're afraid of changes that impact to code we already have, and we don't have the time to ferret out these changes and make working code work again.